# How do i make a string in Lua contain random characters?

Tags: lua

I'm curious on how to make a random string get printed out to the output in Lua I was wondering if this was possible for strings. because I know that you can generate random numbers using the function in Lua called. math.Random() but I'm not sure how to make a string random. how could I make characters in a string random that print to the output?

```
-- I want to print out random characters in a string to the consoles output
local Number = math.random(1,80) -- prints out a number 1-80
print(Number)
```

Comment: A random ASCII character is `string.char(math.random(32,126))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capital letters are in `string.char(math.random(65, 90))` and can be lazy lowered with another string method...

```
local randuppercase = string.char(math.random(65, 65 + 25))
local randlowercase = string.char(math.random(65, 65 + 25)):lower()

print(randlowercase, randuppercase)
-- Example output: g    W
```

Without string method lower() lowercases start at...

```
local randlowercase = string.char(math.random(97, 97 + 25))

print(randlowercase, randlowercase:upper())
-- Sample output: c    C
```

Another possible solve is doing it more oldschool like...

```
local chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" -- The Char Library
local rint = math.random(1, #chars) -- 1 out of length of chars
local rchar = chars:sub(rint, rint) -- Pick it

print(rint, rchar)
-- Sample Output: 12    L
```